# Programmatically choose the class to be instantiate

Tags: vb.net, class, instantiation

I am currently playing around with VB.Net using Visual Studio 2010 (.Net 4.0) and I need your help to create a collection class (let's call it 'cl_MyCollection') with a constructor that accepts two arguments:

1. An `SqlDataReader` object
2. Some means of pointing to a custom class I have created

The scenario is; I have five database tables in SQL 2000 and five VB.Net custom classes.
Each custom class contains a variable for each field of the table the class represents.
For example: "tbl_User" has 2 fields "User_ID" and "User_Name" and tbl_Family" has 3 fields "Family_ID", "Family_Name" and "Family_Location". 
Here is the VB.Net custom class I have created intended to read and store a single record of the "tbl_User" table:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class cl_table_User
    Property User_ID As Integer
    Property User_Name As String

    Public Sub New(ByRef rdr As SqlDataReader)
        Me.User_ID = rdr("User_ID)
        Me.User_Name = rdr("User_Name")
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have created similar classes for the other database tables.

The idea is to perform an SQL statement and use the results to instantiate my intended collection class ('cl_MyCollection'). 
I was thinking something like this: ('conn' is an 'SqlConnection' object)

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select * From tbl_Users", conn)
Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
Dim aCollection as new cl_MyCollection(rdr, "tbl_Users")
```

and later when I want to use "tbl_Family":

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select * From tbl_Family", conn)
Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
Dim aCollection as new cl_MyCollection(rdr, "tbl_Family")
```

As you can see the third line is passing two arguments, the `SQLDataReader` and some means of pointing to a custom class I have created. The constructor of this class will then iterate through the results and create an object of the custom class I created.

I want the second argument to (somehow) make it decide which custom class to use. The 'somehow' is why I am here asking for your help.

The only way I can think this will work is by setting up a select case and list each custom class and then create an object of the custom class but I am hoping there is a better way. Currently I have it set up like this:

```
Public Class cl_MyCollection
    Private records As New Collection

    Public Sub New(rdr As SqlDataReader, selectedClass as string)

         Select Case selectedClass
            Case "tbl_User"

                While (rdr.Read())
                    Dim thisRecord as new cl_table_User(rdr)
                    records.Add(thisRecord)
                End While

            Case "tbl_Family"

                While (rdr.Read())
                    dim thisRecord as new cl_table_Family(rdr)
                    records.Add(thisRecord)
                End While             

         End Select

    End Sub
End Class
```

Ideally I would like the following code to work, or at least the idea it represents:

```
Public Class cl_MyCollection
    Private records As New Collection

    Public Sub New(rdr As SqlDataReader, selectedClass as TYPE)

        While (rdr.Read())
            Dim thisRecord as new selectedClass(rdr)
            records.Add(thisRecord)
        End While

    End Sub
End Class
```

Is this possible? or do I need to stick with the select case?

P.S Sorry for the length of this post.
Edit: Fixed typo, the select case now points to the second argument ('selectedClass') as originally intended.

Comment: Thankyou for the replies, I have had a look at a few ORM techniques and the Collections.Generic library but I am having trouble understanding how to implement either of them to fit my existing code. Can I ask how you guys expect my code to look with the new ideas? From there I should be able to adapt it to suite the rest of my project. Thankyou again for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make things "simpler" and stay away from XML and ORM, you can use generics.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Above link tells about generics, but only examples in C#.

To use a generic in VB.NET it uses (Of type1, type2)  instead of <type1, type2>

Otherwise follow Mitch Wheat's suggestion. ORM is very simple once you know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [Object-Relational Mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software) (ORM), such as NHibernate.

Object-relational mappers do exactly as you describe; they map database tables to code classes, and vice versa.  The ORM will allow you to choose which class to instantiate.

If you just need a way to freeze-dry objects and thaw them, you can store an XML representation of your object in a text field of the database by [serializing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9(VS.71).aspx) it.  If you know the type, this allows you to store any kind of object in a single table.  But you lose the ability to query your objects.